# highest cf between 2 numbers c++

Tags: c++

This is a program to find highest common factor:

```
#include <iostream>
enter code here using namespace std;
void main ()
{
int max=0 , min=0 , x,y,hcf=0;
cout<<"enter 2 numbers\n";
cin>>x>>y;
if (x>y)
{   
    max=x;
    min=y;
}
else if (y>x)
{   
    max=y;
    min=x;
}
if
 (max%min==0)
{ hcf=min;
cout<<"highest cf is:"<<hcf<<endl;}
else
    {
        hcf=min;
do
{
    hcf--;
}
while (max%hcf!=0 && min%hcf!=0);

cout<<"highest cf is:"<<hcf<<endl;
}
        system ("pause");
}
```

although when i test it ; it takes the condition max% hcf !=0 and ignores the second one ... for example if i input 12 and 8 then 12 is called max and 8 is min then it outputs 6 as hcf 
that means it ignored the second condition ... as i understand of course.
so where is my mistake ?

Comment: This is exactly the sort of program where you should learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: Look up short-circuiting. If `max%hcf!=0` is `false`, the entire condition will be `false` anyways - hence no need to evaluate the second term.

Comment: You must stay in the loop while one of the condition **OR** the other is true.  The test in the loop is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A easy solution to get the HCF is to do this.

```
int HCF(int num1, int num2)
{
    for(int i = num1; i > 2; i++)
    {
        if(num1 % i == 0 && num2 % i == 0) return i;
    }
    return 1;
}
```